# Update a XML file and assigning an id to a tag using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to update an XML file and want to assign an ID to a tag. 
In my XML file, there is a tag named "ComponentDetails",  because there are multiple tags with the same name so I want to assign an id to it so that I can select specific values based on ID.
**Following is my XML sample:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <PayrunDetails>
        <PayrunNumber>000777</PayrunNumber>
        <PaidDate>2018-05-15</PaidDate>
    </PayrunDetails>
    <PayLocation>
        <LocationCode>ACT</LocationCode>
        <LocationDescription>ACT</LocationDescription>
        <CompanyDetails>
            <CCode>APPLE</CCode>
            <CName>APPLE Limited</CName>
            <Payslip>
                <StaffNumber>12345</StaffNumber>
                <BankDetails>
                    <BankAccountNo>121212</BankAccountNo>
                </BankDetails>
                <PayDetails>
                    <PayType>NORMAL</PayType>
                    <AmountGross>9999</AmountGross>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType>SALARY</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>1999</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>10616</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType>TAXABLE</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>505</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>7703</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                </PayDetails>
            </Payslip>
            <Payslip>
                <StaffNumber>45555</StaffNumber>
                <BankDetails>
                    <BankAccountNo>131313</BankAccountNo>
                </BankDetails>
                <PayDetails>
                    <PayType>NORMAL</PayType>
                    <AmountGross>9999</AmountGross>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType>SALARY</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>1999</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>10616</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType>GROSS</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>7305</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>76703</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                    <ComponentDetails>
                        <ComponentType>TAXABLE</ComponentType>
                        <Amount>305</Amount>
                        <YTDAmount>6703</YTDAmount>
                    </ComponentDetails>
                </PayDetails>
            </Payslip>
        </CompanyDetails>
    </PayLocation>
</root>
```

From the above XML file, I want to select Amount, YTDAmount subtags values which exist inside the ComponentDetails tags.
Somehow I manage to assign an id to the ComponentDetails tags but unfortunately, subtags exist inside that are missing in the newly created XML file.
**My XSL file is as follow:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ComponentDetails">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="ID">
            <xsl:number/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So pls provide me the solution to create an XML file with a tag id.
I'm fairly new to XSLT so please excuse the potential novice question. Any guidance would be appreciated here.
Thanks in advance.

**I have done the following change and it works:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="PayDetails/ComponentDetails">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="ID">
        <xsl:number/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Should the `ID`s be globally unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get rid of the line

```
<xsl:template match="ComponentDetails/node()"/>
```

because it removes all the subtags of the `ComponentDetails` element.

---

Also, if you want a globally unique `ID`, change the `<xsl:number/>` element to

```
<xsl:number level="any" />
```

Comment: One more problem.. If my tag 'ComponentDetails' varies in numbers, like sometimes ComponentDetails will come 3 times and sometimes more than 3 then how do I identify the tag??

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question, because I thought the ID was to identify the tags. You could access them with `ComponentDetails[@ID='...']`.

Comment: My Problem is that I don't know how to select a tag whose parent tag is generated dynamically and it may come multiple time with the same name but the content of it varies, I mean ComponentDetails tag may appear for each employee one or more times. So I thought if I assign an ID then it may help me out but unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: In my case for the staffNumber 12345 ComponentDetails appear 2 times and for staffNumber 45555 ComponentDetails 3 times, 
and I want to select a value from the salary tag but unable to identify it. I have assigned an ID to the tag but the main problem is that as the ComponentDetails varies so I fail to figure out the at what position the which ComponentType will appear.

Comment: If I understand you right: you can, for example, select the `<ComponentDetails>` element for a given `StaffNumber` and get its `Amount` with `//ComponentDetails[ComponentType='SALARY' and ../../StaffNumber='12345']/Amount`, or, if your current node is `<PayDetails>`, with `ComponentDetails[ComponentType='SALARY' and ../../StaffNumber='12345']/Amount` which would be faster and cleaner.